# Unable to read JVM parameter set through eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jvm

In Eclipse I set the following JVM (system) parameter (Window -> Preferences -> Tomcat -> JVM Settings -> Append to JVM Parameters):

```
file.read=c:\user\data.ini
```

Now when I try to read the same parameter using the following command from my program
`System.getProperty("data.ini");` it returns a null value.

Can someone help figure out what I am doing wrong ?

I am using Tomcat version 6.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the parameter in the following format:

```
-Dfile.read=c:\user\data.ini
```

And then get the parameter with the following line of code:

```
String value = System.getProperty("file.read");
```